# How to get all clickable elements in the DOM and click them at random

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I made what I thought was a very straightforward script

```
var gatherClickElements = function(curnode, gathered)
{
    if(typeof curnode.onclick === 'function')
        gathered.push(curnode);
    curnode.childNodes.forEach(function(child) {
        gatherClickElements(child, gathered);       
    });
};

var clickElems = [];

gatherClickElements(document.documentElement, clickElems);

setInterval(function() {
    var rand = clickElems[Math.floor(Math.random() * clickElems.length)];
    rand.onclick();
}, 100);
```

to try randomly click every clickable element in the DOM, but it is not working. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what exact issue you are facing?

Comment: How is it not working? Does the console show the results of `rand.onclick` etc ?

Comment: (rand.onclick) is not going to click anything... You are checking to see if they have an onclick on that element

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: can you post your source with entire html. So that we can find the solution?

Comment: @adeneo Sorry, I forgot to post the correct code. Look now.

Comment: Please post html source as well. I tried with sample html and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

This will click random elements:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var rand = clickElems[Math.floor(Math.random() * clickElems.length)];
   rand.click(); 
console.log(rand.onclick);
}, 100);
```

Comment: change rand.onclick(); to rand.click();

Comment: Gives me errors like  Cannot read property 'Click' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:16:6